# Batch Script to switch files depending on userinput

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

How it should work/What it should do:

At C:\Users\RandomUser/Game I want to replace the file at C:\Users\RandomUser/Game/ConsoleVariables.ini.
In order to do so the user should prepare a folder with his different ini files and that path will be hardcoded in the .bat script. 
After running the script it will count how many .ini files were found in the hardcoded path (works) and display them in cmd with a number from 1 to n behind the files so the user sees what number to press to choose the according file. [CMD-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiwqB.jpg)

If the user enters a number (validation check would be nice) the original .ini file at the game location should be deleted and be replaced by the .ini file which he chose and the copied ini file should be renamed to ConsoleVariables.ini (the file will be copied so it won't disappear in the folder so it can be re done).

What I have working:
1) loop through all ini files and display them with the number from 1 to n behind them
2) I know how to copy/paste files

What's missing:
1) Get userinput(number) and copy the according file depending on the input(Not sure how to loop/map the userinput to the actual ini files so 1 is actually bound to the first .ini file and so on)
2) rename copied file to ConsoleVariables.ini but don't change the name from the original file

```
@echo off
set iniFolder=C:\Users\RandomUser\Inis
set iniDestinationFolder=C:\Users\RandomUser/Game

setlocal enableextensions
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count = 0
set /a c=0
FOR %%i in (%iniFolder%\*.txt) DO set /a count+=1 & set /a c=c+1 & echo %%i !c!
echo *****%count% ini files found*****
echo press the according number to replace your ini file (1 - %count%)
endlocal
::logic missing here
set /P id=Enter number:
If id==1 goto accepted
:accepted
del %iniDestinationFolder%\Test.txt
xcopy %iniFolder%\Test2.txt %iniDestinationFolder%
pause
```

**Note:** In the example above im using .txt files instead of .ini files for testing purposes.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `set count = 0` sets a variable named `count` + _space_ to a value like _space_ + `0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily by using an array like this code below :

```bat
@echo off
set "iniFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Inis"
set "iniDestinationFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Game"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
REM Just replace the variable "Ext=txt" by "Ext=ini" after testing it with text files !
Set "Ext=txt"

echo(
REM In this loop (FOR .. DO) ==> We fill the list files into an array
FOR %%f in ("%iniFolder%\*.%Ext%") DO (
    SET /a "Count+=1"
    set "list[!Count!]=%%~nxf"
    set "listpath[!Count!]=%%~dpFf"
)

REM In this loop (FOR..DO) ==> Display array elements in order to show the list files found
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    echo %%i-!list[%%i]!
)
echo(
echo *****%count% %Ext% files found*****
Set /a "First=%count%-%count% + 1"
echo press the according number to replace your %Ext% file (%First% - %count%)

Set /p "Input="
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) Do (
    If [%INPUT%]==[%%i] (
        xcopy /I /F "!listpath[%%i]!" "%iniDestinationFolder%\"
    )
)
pause & exit
```

Comment: @Julian 
Welcome on Stack Overflow.
Please take Stack Overflow (SO) [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to say thanks on SO by accepting an answer on being helpful by clicking on gray check mark symbol left to an answer.
See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)
A question with no accepted answer is rated as a not answered question even if there are good answers.

Comment: How would I rename the file thats being copied to ConsoleVariables.ini when I paste it?

Comment: @Julian Just replace the last line by this one `xcopy /I /F /Y "!listpath[%%i]!" "%iniDestinationFolder%\ConsoleVariables.ini"`

Comment: @Julian, use `copy` rather than `xcopy` and append the target name: `copy /Y "!listpath[%%i]!" "!iniDestinationFolder!\ConsoleVariables.ini"`...

Comment: What is the line `Set /a "First=%count%-%count% + 1"` for? it just sets the variable `First` to a value of `1`... And I would replace `set /P "Input="` by `set "Input=0" & set /P Input="" && findstr "^[0123456789][0123456789]*$" > nul || goto :Repeat` and put the label `:Repeat` just before that line so there is some kind of validation...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have less than 10 ini files in the directory, we can use choice instead:

```
@echo off
set "iniFolder=%userprofile%\Inis"
set "iniDestinationFolder=%userprofile%\Game"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
for %%i in ("%inifolder%\*.txt") DO (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "file!cnt!=%%~nxi"
    set chc=!chc!!cnt!
    call echo !cnt!. %%file!cnt!%%
)
choice /c !chc! /m "Select a file"
copy /Y "%iniFolder%\!file%errorlevel%!" "%iniDestinationFolder%\ConsoleVariables.ini"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right now it doesn't delete/copy any file for me.
The start cmd screen also doesn't show the actual files(see screenshot).

https://imgur.com/2oqDXJA

Comment: Not sure why but the cmd prompt instantly closes again after executing the batch file.

Comment: add pause at the bottom of the batch file to see why

Comment: then your foldernames are incorrect. make sure you update `inifolder` and `inidestinationfolder`